# Sort item in listview columns

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i have a listview with diffrent columns ID, Name, Zipcode, City, Country, Phone, Email
And i have two Forms, Form1 and Form2

In the First form i have the listview with the columns
On the second Form i have a Custom manager with diffrent Listboxes where you can type in the customer information (ex Name, Zipcode, City, etc)

**I want the information in Form2 to be sorted after the columns in Form1**. ex the "name" Texbox in Form2 should be inserted in Form1 listview under the column Name, and The textbox Zipcode text should be inserted under the Zipcode column.

[picture http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/3486/skiten1.png](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/3486/skiten1.png)

It's hard because im little bit of a beginner and to follow diffrent sites didn't help me.

Please what can i do.

Form1

```
InitializeComponent();


listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.LabelEdit = true;
listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
listView1.GridLines = true;
listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
listView1.Columns.Add("ID", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Zipcode", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("City", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Country", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Phone", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Email", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

Form2

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           contact.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
           firstName = contact.FirstName;

           contact.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
           lastName = contact.LastName;
```

Form2

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainForm main = new MainForm();

            contact.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
            firstName = contact.FirstName;

            contact.LastName = tbLastName.Text;
            lastName = contact.LastName;
```

still Form2

```
 public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}]", contact.ToString());

    }
```

**//Here comes the Contact class**

```
class Contact
    {
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName
```

In the Contact class there is also properties of the above variables and then a ToString like this

```
public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}]", firstName, lastName);


        }
```

Form1

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ColumnHeader columnheader;
            ListViewItem listviewitem;

            // Ensure that the view is set to show details.
            listView1.View = View.Details;
if (customerframe.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //if button OK is clicked then value will be inserted
            {
                listviewitem = new ListViewItem(contact.FirstName);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(contact.LastName);
this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
```

I dont really know know how much code you need for helping me, moreover, my code is very messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not exactly "sorting" in the traditional sense.  You are just trying to add a `ListViewItem` into the ListView control and then add more information into that ListViewItem's SubItems.

An example would look something like this:

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(yourID);
lvi.SubItems.Add(contact.Fullname);
lvi.SubItems.Add(zipcode);
lvi.SubItems.Add(city);
lvi.SubItems.Add(address.country);
lvi.SubItems.Add(phone);
lvi.SubItems.Add(email);

listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Update:

Your customerFrame class (Form2) doesn't look like it has the reference to your `Contact` reference.

Your customerFrame return a Contact object with the data filled out.  Something like this:

```
Public Contact GetContact() {
  Contact contact = new Contact();
  contact.FirstName = tbFirstName.Text;
  // etc.
  return contact;
}
```

And then your Form1 call should look something like this:

```
using (var customerFrame = new CustomerFrame()) {
  if (customerFrame.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    Contact contact = customerFrame.GetContact();

    listviewitem = new ListViewItem(contact.FirstName);
    listviewitem.SubItems.Add(contact.LastName);
    // etc.
    this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm when doing this i get empty items in listview

 `if (customerframe.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
                listviewitem = new ListViewItem(contact.FirstName);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(contact.LastName);
                listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.ZipCode);
                
                this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);

}`

Comment: @user1067973 The code you posted doesn't show the relationship between form1 and form2.  How are they talking to each other?

Comment: I put some more code in my post maybe this can make you help me

Comment: @user1067973 How does you `contact` class get reference in form2 by form1?  That's the code you aren't showing.  That's *probably* why things might not be working.

Comment: @user1067973 I added an example of how Form1 and Form2 can talk to each other.  It is very unclear how your `contact` class is getting the information from Form2.